# Trying a pi day nn, not predicting correctly

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm attempting to make a simple neural net to "learn" pi, and the odd thing is the prediction of this simple neural network is always one??

I know this is not a great use case but I wanted to see if Neural net could find pi this way...

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax',input_dim=1))
train_x = np.array([1,2,3,4,10])
train_y = [x*3.14 for x in train_x]
print(train_y)

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=300, batch_size=10)

print( model.predict( np.array([.5])) )
print( model.predict( np.array([2.5])) )
```

Comment: Even more telling, it returns a prediction of `1` for each of the training values.

Comment: Look at your loss function and accuracy: they never change.  Your model isn't learning anything.  I suggest that you return to the basic examples in your tutorial, and check your process for training a model.  If you're still having trouble, cite the source you're using.

Comment: Softmax with one neuron makes no sense, it will always produce output of 1.0

Comment: use `relu` or `linear` for your activation function